# How to use gl_LastFragData in WEBGL?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm currently working on a `THREE.JS` project. I need to customize a fragment_shader with programmable blending instead of using predefined blending. To do this, I want to use `gl_LastFragData` in my fragment_shader. But I got this error.[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr5K1.png)

How can I use gl_LastFragData in WEBGL or is there any other equivalent way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `gl_LastFragData` in WebGL. WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, WebGL2 is based on OpenGL ES 3.0. Neither of those support `gl_LastFragData`

The traditional way of using a previous result is to pass it in as a texture when generating the next result

```
someOperation1(A, B)            -> TempTexture1
someOperation2(TempTexture1, C) -> TempTexture2
someOperation3(TempTexture2, D) -> TempTexture1
someOperation4(TempTexture1, E) -> TempTexture2
someOperation5(TempTexture2, F) -> resultTexture/fb/canvas/window
```

[Example](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html)

Comment: hi @gman, I'm using `WEBGL1` and i'm overriding `meshphsicalframent_shader`. I need to use custom blending function instead of predefined blnding functions like `blendFunc(gl.ONE,gl.ONE)` so I'd like to do something like `gl_FragData[0] = color+ gl_LastFragData[0] * weight`;  Any ideas?

Comment: hi @gman, is there something equivalent to `blBlendfunci` in  WEBGL1?

Answer (score 1):

`gl_LastFragData` is not present in webgl or opengl specs.
Hovewer there is [extensions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Extension) mechanism in these API's.

You can query for available extensions on program start and see if desired features are available. To use available extension in shader program you should [activate](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Extensions) it in shader source code.

You error message says that you try to use extension functionality when it is unavailable.

Speaking of your exact case - check [EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) extension. Also worth checking [ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARM/ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt), NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch.

Hovewer these extensions are written against OpenGL 2.0, OpenGL ES2.0. I'm not sure if they do exist as [webgl extensions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/).

Expect framebuffer fetch functionality to be present on mobile devices and not present on desktop devices. As far as I understand that comes from difference between GPU architectures for mobile and desktop (tile-based vs immediate mode rasterizers). Tile-based gpu can use tile local memory for effective lookup.

Comment: Hi @mlnk, How can I apply blendFunc for `gl_FragData[0]` and `gl_FragData[1] `separately?